# CoreUI DataTable sort values by specific column values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, core-ui

**Right now, it's not showing sorted result according to **`title`**. I want to show the rows by default in `ascending`.**

Please have a look:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
const fields = [
  { key: 'title', _classes: 'font-weight-bold' },
  { key: 'category', _style: { width: '20%'} }
]
```

```
<CDataTable
    items={list}
    fields={fields}
    columnFilter
    tableFilter={{ 'placeholder': 'Type something...'}}
    itemsPerPageSelect
    itemsPerPage={5}
    hover
    sorter
    pagination
/>
```

---

**Note:** From the [Documentation](https://coreui.io/react/docs/3.3/components/CDataTable/): I have tried something i.e. `sorter={{'resetable': 'ascending'}}` but nothing works for me.

Comment: Is there any initialstate?

Comment: Hmm, yes. `const [list, setList] = useState([])`

Comment: I read the doc for your question and don't find right thing.

Comment: Hmm, yeah bro :|

Comment: Is CoreUI use https://github.com/coreui/coreui-datatables for DataTables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two points:

1. For descending sort you must set `asc:false`
2. Default sort value must pass to `sorterValue` option in `CDataTable`

So , you can try this:

```
<CDataTable
    items={list}
    fields={fields}
    columnFilter
    tableFilter={{ 'placeholder': 'Type something...'}}
    itemsPerPageSelect
    itemsPerPage={5}
    hover
    sorter
    sorterValue={{column: "title", asc: true}}
    pagination
/>
```

Comment: They have a very poor documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for me:

```
<CDataTable
  items={list}
  fields={fields}
  columnFilter
  tableFilter={{ 'placeholder': 'Type something...'}}
  itemsPerPageSelect
  itemsPerPage={5}
  hover
  sorter
  sorterValue={{column: "title", asc: true}}
  onSorterValueChange={(params) => {
    if (params.column === order.sorting.column && params.asc === order.sorting.asc) return;
    dispatch(actions.getOrders(.....));
    dispatch(actions.sortingChanged(params));
  }}
  pagination
/>
```

You should avoid cyclic code call by making sure in onSorterValueChange() that params.column & params.asc are not equal to what is already set. If true - return; otherwise - call your API request and change state with new sorting params.